# БД Oracle в локальной сети с двумя доменами

Tags: oracle

В локальной сети (192.168.0.0/24) два домена domen1.local и domen2.local БД Oracle 9g установлена на контролере домена domen1.local (WinServer2003), также имеется в этой сети второй домен со своим контролером домена (WinServer2016) и своими ПК (Win10), теперь вывожу ПК из первого домена завожу во второй домен и теперь этот ПК с Win10 не хочет коннектится к БД Oracle.
Подскажите какие настройки влияют на подключение, у ПК фаервол отключен , пинг идет и по айпишнику и по имени